# How to pass vector elements as individual arguments to a function in R

Tags: r

I am working on a web scraping project using rvest.

```
html_text(html_nodes(url, CSS))
```

extracts data from `url` wherever the matching `CSS` is found. My problem is that the website I am scraping uses a unique `CSS ID` for each listed product (such as `ListItem_001_Price`). So 1 `CSS` defines exactly 1 item's price and so automated webscraping doesn't work

I can create a vector

```
V <- c("ListItem_001_Price", "ListItem_002_Price", "ListItem_003_Price")
```

for all the products' `CSS` IDs manually. Is it  possible to pass it's individual elements to the `html_nodes()` function in one go and so collect the resulting data back as a single vector/dataframe?

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` here:

```
V <- c("ListItem_001_Price", "ListItem_002_Price", "ListItem_003_Price")
results <- lapply(V, function(x) html_text(html_nodes(url, x)))
```

I assume here that your nested call to `html_text` will in general return a character vector of the text corresponding to the matching nodes, for each item in `V`.  This would leave you with a list of vectors which you can then access.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works perfectly! The 'function(x)' inside apply was what I couldn't figure out - great to see it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`html_nodes()` needs the initial "." to find your tags by css-class. You could manually create

`V <- c(".ListItem_001_Price", ".ListItem_002_Price", ".ListItem_003_Price")`

like you sugest, but I recommend that you user regex to match the classes like `'ListItem_([0-9]{3})_Price'` so you can avoid the manual labour. Make sure you regex on the actual string of your markup, and not on the html-node object. (see below)

In R, apply(), lapplay(), sapplay() and the like, work much like a short loop. In it you can apply a function to every member of data-type that contains numerous values, like lists, data-frames, matrixes or vectors.

In your case, it's a vector, and a way to beginning to understand how it works is thinking of it like:

`sapply(vector, function(x) THING-TO-DO-WITH-ITEM-IN-VECTOR)`

In your case, you'd like the *thing to do with item in vector* to be the fetching of the html_text corresponding to the items in the vector.
See the code below for an example:

```
library(rvest)
# An example piece of html
example_markup <- "<ul>
<li class=\"ListItem_041_Price\">Brush</li>
<li class=\"ListItem_031_Price\">Phone</li>
<li class=\"ListItem_002_Price\">Paper clip</li>
<li class=\"ListItem_012_Price\">Bucket</li>
</ul>"
html <- read_html(example_markup)


# Avoid manual creation of css with regex
regex <- 'ListItem_([0-9]{3})_Price'
# Note that ([0-9]{3}) will match three consecutive numeric characters
price_classes <- regmatches(example_markup, gregexpr(regex, example_markup))[[1]]
# Paste leading "." so that html_nodes() can find the class:
price_classes <- paste(".", price_classes, sep="")

# A singel entry is found like so:
html %>% html_nodes(".ListItem_031_Price") %>% html_text()

# Use sapply to get a named character vector of your products
# Note how ".ListItem_031_Price" from the line above is replaced by x
# which will be each item of price_classes in turn.
products <- sapply(price_classes, function(x) html %>% html_nodes(x) %>% html_text())
```

The result in products is a named character vector. Use `unname(products)` to drop the names.

Comment: Great explanations mate, learned a lot from your rich post! Thanks for sharing other functions here.